# Referred vs is Referred

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I had a question, which of the sentences is correct? If both please explain the usage of each.

> ’Attitude’ is referred to as how a person thinks or feels about someone or something
>
> ’Attitude’ referred to as how a person thinks or feels about someone or something

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second sentence is more correct.

"*something* is referred to" is the passive form of "referred *something* to". This sense is used with the transitive senses of the verb, as in a doctor referring a patient to a specialist.

But in this case, the word "attitude" is doing the referring, it's not being referred by someone else.

But in both cases, the word "as" is not appropriate. It should be:

> "Attitude" referred to how a person thinks or feels about something or someone.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

> "Attitude" refers to how a person thinks or feels about someone or something

See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/refer

> refer to (of a word, phrase, or symbol) describe or denote; have as a referent.
>   ‘the star refers to items which are intended for the advanced learner’